# Looking for the name of a particular device

Tags: soft-question, terminology, gyroscopes

Please move this if it's not in the right location.

I'm looking for the name of a device that I frequently see in many scenarios, specifically that of an office/library which can be described as having multiple rings that rotate in various directions. I was thinking it was a gyroscope or perhaps a celestial globe, but something tells me that it's not quite what I'm looking for. I recall that there is a movie production company which uses this device as their symbolic figure of their logo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The device you are describing is a [Cardan suspension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gimbal).

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that they had a different name! Been calling them gyroscopes my whole life!